# Bash - inside a "for" loop if a condition is met once or more - take action

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script :

```
for sha1 in $(git log origin/$current_branch..HEAD --format=format:%H);do
comment=$(git cat-file commit $sha1 | sed '1,/^$/d')
    if [[ $comment == *oops!* ]]; then touch oops ; else : ; fi ; done
    if [ -e oops ]; then
      rm -f oops    
      return 0 #0=oops! string exists in comment
    else
      return 1 #1=oops! string doesn't exists in comment  
    fi  
}
```

Which is working great for me,

In this script, I am checking if the string **"oops!"** is inside any of the sha1 commit messages and if that is the case I return 0 from this function.
What is bothering me is the fact that I create a temporary file called oops (using touch) and then delete it.

Is there a way to check inside for loop if a condition is met once or more, and if so -  do something (In my case return 0) ***without having to create a file.***

The reason I need this is that I want my script not to be affected by any r/w permissions.

Comment: If you are using `return`, your loop never iterates more than once. That said, the return status of `[[ $comment == .. ]]` is your desired return status; just make that line the last command of the function.

Comment: @chepner That will not work. it will only take one sha1 and return the value for him

Comment: That's what's already happening; the `return` command exits the loop immediately. It's not clear what he actually wants (though probably exit immediately with 1 if there is match, return 0 if you get through the loop without exiting. (Yes, I'm inverting the return value as well in my interpretation.)

Comment: ok,
So this is why I created the file with "touch" so it will finish the loop, and the return is coming only after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understood your problem but why don't you just return when your condition is met?

```
for sha1 in $(git log origin/$current_branch..HEAD --format=format:%H);do
    comment=$(git cat-file commit $sha1 | sed '1,/^$/d')
    if [[ $comment == *oops!* ]]; then 
      return 0 #0=oops! string exists in comment
    fi  
done
return 1 #1=oops! string doesn't exists in comment
```

This would return 0 if the condition is met else 1...

Comment: I'd go a step further; skip the command substitution, and put `git cat-file commit "$sha1" | sed '1,/^$/d' | grep -q 'oops!' && return 0` in the loop.

Comment: (It's not clear if it should return 0 if *any* commit matches, or if *all* commits match, but that's easily fixed as necessary pending feedback from the OP.)

Comment: it should return 0 if any commit matches.
With @Renaud Pacalet answer I don't see any "done" to close the "do",
am I right?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan You are right, of course, I copy-pasted from the OP's code without checking first. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @chepner On a performance point of view your proposal is not necessarily better: you invoke the external `grep` command instead of a built-in. And on a readability / maintainability point of view, I think the less compact form is significantly better. But I agree that it is also a matter of taste.

Comment: I would also suggest replacing the `sed`/`grep` combo with a single call to `awk`, which mitigates the approach somewhat.

Comment: (I wonder if `git grep` alone is sufficient to replace the whole thing.)